# MHC haplotypes and COVID-19

Tags: covid-19, immune-system

Have there been any studies done looking at samples of MHC haplotypes in patients infected with SARS-CoV-2?

It would be interesting to see if certain HLA polymorphisms are associated with more severe disease.

Given that only a certain percent percentage of patients generate a robust inflammatory response in the lungs might suggest that certain haplotypes of the MHC class two receptors elicit a signaling cascade for cytokine overproduction via antigen presentation to macrophages.

Answer (score 2):

There haven't been any completed studies though looking at clinicaltrials.gov there appear to be some recruiting or in progress.

There has been [an in silico study of HLA susceptibility and they conclude HLA-B*46:01 may be vulnerable and HLA-B*15:03 may help to protect](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32303592/)

> Genetic variability across the three major histocompatibility complex (MHC) class I genes (human leukocyte antigen [lsqb]HLA[rsqb] A, B, and C) may affect susceptibility to and severity of severe acute respiratory syndrome 2 (SARS-CoV-2), the virus responsible for coronavirus disease 2019 (COVID-19). We execute a comprehensive in silico analysis of viral peptide-MHC class I binding affinity across 145 HLA -A, -B, and -C genotypes for all SARS-CoV-2 peptides. We further explore the potential for cross-protective immunity conferred by prior exposure to four common human coronaviruses. The SARS-CoV-2 proteome is successfully sampled and presented by a diversity of HLA alleles. However, we found that HLA-B*46:01 had the fewest predicted binding peptides for SARS-CoV-2, suggesting individuals with this allele may be particularly vulnerable to COVID-19, as they were previously shown to be for SARS. Conversely, we found that HLA-B*15:03 showed the greatest capacity to present highly conserved SARS-CoV-2 peptides that are shared among common human coronaviruses, suggesting it could enable cross-protective T-cell based immunity.
>
> <sup>Nguyen A, David JK, Maden SK, et al. Human leukocyte antigen susceptibility map for SARS-CoV-2 [published online ahead of print, 2020 Apr 17]. J Virol. 2020;JVI.00510-20. doi:10.1128/JVI.00510-20</sup>